# Handle video player orientation change like YouTube app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, youtube

I would like to know the best way to handle the device orientation change while viewing a video like how it works in the YouTube app. In landscape, the video is full screen but when the user rotates to portrait the video is pinned to top of screen and a list of 'recommended' videos are listed below it. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube only takes care the orientation when rotation of device is unlock.
If you want to do like this, implement this function
`(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

to handle when orientation changes.